# HTML can't find files on ubuntu

Tags: html, image, ubuntu, path

I've made this small webpage stored in `/var/www/html` with name of index.html
I've included some images but html can't locate those images though the path seems to be correct!
Info::
On running:
        `cd /var/www/html/pics/boys ls`
in terminal, result comes out as :
        `a1.jpg a2.jpg b1.jpg b2.jpg*`

HTML code::

```html
<div id="question">
  <h3>Who is cooler?</h3>
</div>
<div class="outerContainer">
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="pics/boys/a1.jpg" alt="Contastant1" id="leftImg">
  </div>
  <div id="or">
    <h1>OR</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="imgContainer">
    <img src="pics/boys/a2.jpg" alt="Contanstant2" id="rightImg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheets and javascript are working!!!
For full HTML code, pls comment. **The same code is working in windows**

Comment: Where is the index.html file located? By making your url "pics/...." instead of "/pics/..." it will look for the pics folder relative to the location of index.html file NOT your webroot.

Comment: @thatidiotguy - index.html is located in /var/www/html. I've tried /pics/... instead of pics/.... but no improvement

Comment: That is strange. Is it perhaps a permission issue? Does the pics folder and the associated subfolders and files have the appropriate permissions to be accessed by your web server? (if you are running this through apache, which appears to be true based on the file locations)

Comment: It might be a permission issue. Try running `cd /var/www/html/pics/boys; ls -l` to see which user owns these files.

Comment: @thatidiotguy I'm not sure how to give web server's permissions but yes every folder and sub folder has root privileges.

Comment: @andrechalom **Root** for every file

Comment: I would recommend looking into linux permissions as it seems highly likely that this is the cause of the problem. If you navigate to the picture directly in your web browser what status code is returned? i.e. point your browser to localhost/photos/boys/a1.jpg. If it returns forbidden then it is a permissions issue.

Comment: NOT even in windows but the webpage is displaying images on Ubuntu too, in the media directory instead of ROOT @andrechalom

Comment: YES! @thatidiotguy It's forbidden. But how to give it privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the best approach here is to make sure that the files are owned by the same user that is running the Apache server. First, you need to determine which user is it. It's probably www-data if you are running Ubuntu, but you can check it by typing `ps -ef | grep apache2`. You should see some lines like:

> root       979     1  0 11:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>
> www-data  1012   979  0 11:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>
> www-data  1013   979  0 11:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
>
> www-data  1014   979  0 11:19 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

The first field here is the user that's running the Apache server. Then make sure ALL files in the /var/www/html directory are owned by this user:

`sudo chown -R www-data /var/www/html`

The chown program "CHanges OWNership", and the -R flag means "recursive", that is, apply the same user for every subdirectory and file.

Incidentally, if this is working fine on Windows it's because Windows file ownership and permissions work very differently ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your html coding, you only need to give the permission to the image file.

Either change the permission to folder or image file-

1. image folder$:  sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/pics/boys
2. image file $: sudo chmod 777 /var/www/pics/boys/a1.jpg

Comment: It says 'permission denied'